How to assign the maximum value of the other variable to a variable by group?
ID  Time  Condition Seq Want_temp Want_final_v1 

A   1     yes       0   0         0             
A   2     yes       0   .         1             
A   3     no        1   .         .             
A   4     yes       0   .         2             
A   5     no        1   .         .             
A   6     no        2   .         .             
B   1     yes       0   .         4             
B   2     no        1   .         .             
B   3     no        2   .         .             
B   4     no        3   .         .             
B   5     no        4   .         .             
B   6     yes       0   0         0             
B   7     yes       0   0         0             
...    

This is a simplified version of a data set I have. The variable I want  to generate is Want_final_v1.
Seq is the numerical sequence starting from 0 when the value of  Condition is "yes". Seq increases by 1 when the next value of Condition is "no".
What I want is Want_final_v1 which contains 0 for Condition == "yes" but contains the last or the max value of Seq for Condition == "yes" only when following values for Condition == "no".
My initial plan is to generate Want_final_v1 after generating Want_temp (which I've done).

I think "following" here may mean "followed by">

This was a fun question that seemed like it should have a simple elegant solution, but I could not find one. Interested to see if someone has a better solution.
Stata assigns values row by row going top down. This is why I am reversing the sort order to be able to carry the last "no" value down to the corresponding "yes" value.
* Example generated by -dataex-. For more info, type help dataex
clear
input str1 id byte time str3 condition byte(seq want_temp want_final_v1)
"A" 1 "yes" 0 0 0
"A" 2 "yes" 0 . 1
"A" 3 "no"  1 . .
"A" 4 "yes" 0 . 2
"A" 5 "no"  1 . .
"A" 6 "no"  2 . .
"B" 1 "yes" 0 . 4
"B" 2 "no"  1 . .
"B" 3 "no"  2 . .
"B" 4 "no"  3 . .
"B" 5 "no"  4 . .
"B" 6 "yes" 0 0 0
"B" 7 "yes" 0 0 0
end

* Reverse sort order
gsort -id -time

* Initiate want variable
gen want = .

* Get the last "no" value in each group
replace want = seq if (condition == "no" & condition[_n-1] == "yes")

* For all values that was not a last "no" value, get the value from preceding row
replace want = want[_n-1] if missing(want)

* Set "yes" obs in group with no "no" to 0
replace want = 0 if missing(want)

* Replace all "no" rows with missing
replace want = . if condition == "no" 

* Restore sort order
sort id time

